# Decode Msgpack to JSON golang

Tags: json, go, msgpack

How to serialize msgpack file to JSON on golang using github.com/vmihailenco/msgpack module

```
file, err := os.Open("current.msgpack")
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
}
defer file.Close()

decoder := msgpack.NewDecoder(file)
item := make(map[string]interface{})
decoder.Decode(&item)

fmt.Println(item) // output map[]
```

}

Comment: You're sure your file isn't empty?

Comment: Do check errors!

Comment: Yes, file isn't empty.
`decoder.Decode(&item)` returns error `msgpack: invalid code=ca decoding map length`